# Get removed lines from two files python

Tags: python, diff, difflib

I have two files, and I don't have any problem getting the new lines in `new file` but I can't get the removed ones in `new_file` compared with `old_file`. 
I get all the lines. How can I get too the removed lines?

```
import difflib
old_file=open(OUTPUT).readlines()
new_file=open(TMP_FILE).readlines()

diff = difflib.unified_diff(old_file, new_file, fromfile='file1', tofile='file2', lineterm='', n=0)
lines = list(diff)[2:]
added = [line[1:] for line in lines if line[0] == '+']
removed = [line[1:] for line in lines if line[0] == '-']

added_users=[]
for line in added:
    if line not in removed:
        added_users.append(line)
```

Comment: I have tested your code and I get the removed lines. Could you provide some data for OUTPUT and TMP_FILE?

Comment: Actually you where right. I was using a malformed input so it was giving me false positives. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use the `comm` to diff files.

```
NAME
   comm - compare two sorted files line by line

SYNOPSIS
   comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2

DESCRIPTION
   Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.

   With no options, produce three-column output. 
   Column one contains lines unique to FILE1,
   column two contains lines unique to FILE2, 
   and column three contains lines common to both files.

   -1     suppress lines unique to FILE1

   -2     suppress lines unique to FILE2

   -3     suppress lines that appear in both files
```

So you can do follws

```
comm -1 old new > removed
comm -2 old new > added
```

The input files must be sorted. If they are not, sort them first.

```
comm -1 <(sort old) <sort(new) > removed
```

Comment: I want to use python as I said in the post. Thank you